# Where do I locate certificates generated for local HTTPs server in C#

Tags: c#, ssl

I am able to generate SSL certificate for local URL.

It is generated successfully as shown in image below,

[image]

```
 var certStore = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);
```

But I am unable to locate this certificate inside `currentUser` directory.

Is it the correct location where SSL certificates are stored? Or am I looking at wrong place?

If I use https://google.com instead of `localwebserver` this is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to go to RUN > MMC > File > Add/Remove Snapin..

Click on Certificates then click Add..

Choose Computer Account then Local Computer... Then click OK.

You will see all your certificates there..

or you can locate it on your IIS in Server Certificates